# Cannot open file

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, filesystem, file

[image]

I need to open the "retroarch-joypads" folder and open a file inside it. For some reason file manger can't open the folder. Can anyone tell me how to open it?

Edit: The command:

```
sudo pcmanfm
```

does not work. I'm using raspbien buster.

Comment: Open an LXTerminal and run `sudo pcmanfm`. Be afraid, be very afraid because one false move using that can destroy your system - only use it to edit the retroarch stuff, then forget you've ever known how to do that.

Comment: @Dougie Sorry, but that did not work.

Comment: So are you not running RaspiOS? Because it works on my system here.

Comment: @Dougie I am running the raspberry pi os. "buster" Is there a different one I need to run?

Comment: On the tool bar there's a little icon with a blue bar at the top and `>_` in the middle. Click that. Once the window appears click it with your mouse. Type `sudo -s [ENTER]`. You should get `root@raspberrypi:/home/pi`. Type `pcmanfm [ENTER]` and that should launch the file manager with /home/pi as the current directory.

Comment: @Dougie it opens the filebrowser, but when I click on the the retroarchjoypads it asks me how to open it.

Comment: Open with leafpad or mousepad (yes that is a stupid name for an editor).

Comment: @Dougie retroarch-joypads is a folder, I need one of the files inside it.

Comment: Get the `sudo -s` shell running then don't bother starting pcmanfm, just drive down the filesystem hierarchy with the `cd` command. When you find the files you need to edit use `nano`